# Are MS Office 2010 profiles backwards compatible with 2007

Tags: windows, user-profile, microsoft-office-2010

We run a VDI environment in which user profiles are stored on the D: drive.  If I upgrade our "master" image from Office 2007 to 2010 (which will only change C:) and redeploy the VMs, will there be (compatibility) problems with users' profiles & their Office settings, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Without doing any research whatsoever, I can almost guarantee you will have no problems migrating profiles from 2007 to 2010.  That has to be the most common use-case Microsoft would have tested when releasing the new product.

If for some reason you were back-revving from 2010 to 2007, that's where you might encounter difficulty depending on what 2010 actually does to the Office settings.

Comment: So the installer wouldn't touch/upgrade any of the profiles on the system?

Comment: The only profile the installer might touch is the profile for whichever account the installer is running under.

Comment: Depending on config options the All Users profile could also be affected.